# jQuery doesn' add active class to nav menu

Tags: jquery

I've written a little bit of jQuery to dynamically add a `active` class to the `li` item in the nav menu that has been clicked.

However for some reason, the `active` class is not add to the `li` element that was clicked. Does someone has an idea why the class isn't added?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navigation-menu  a').click(function() {
    //removing the previous selected menu state
    $('.navigation-menu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    //adding the state for this parent menu
    $(this).parents("li").addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active { border: 1px solid red  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul id="js-navigation-menu" class="navigation-menu show">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="">link_to 'ABOUT', page_path('about')</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="">link_to "PEOPLE", members_path</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="">link_to "RESEARCH", projects_path</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="">link_to "PUBLICATIONS", publications_path</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="">link_to 'CONTACT', page_path('contact')</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="">link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks for your help.

update:

adding preventDefault() to the click event makes the code work, however, after this, the link is no longer working :(

I found this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/Vitaa/ActiveNavigation) and it works like a charm!

Comment: change to this, $('.navigation-menu  li').click(function () {

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/epLxgLd2/. Check the console for errors

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using pure HTML. Your snippet does not work when it is full of server side code

Comment: that's odd, I'm not getting any errors in the console. Maybe the script is overwritten somewhere else.

Comment: You also need to preventDefault on the links: `$('.navigation-menu  a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...` - please update my snippet changes to reflect your actual code

Comment: hi mplungjan, yes adding preventDefault() fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oops, after adding e.preventDefault() , my nav links aren't working any longer!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navigation-menu  li').click(function () {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this jQuery plugin fixed my problem:

https://github.com/Vitaa/ActiveNavigation